# What is the difference between propName={() => functionName(varName)} and propName={functionName(varName)} in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am learning react from Bob Ziroll's tutorial and there is a code

```
<Die key={die.id} value={die.value} isHeld={die.isHeld} holdDice={() => holdDice(die.id)}/>
```

the part
`holdDice={() => holdDice(die.id)}`
works

but when i try
`holdDice={holdDice(die.id)}`
it doesn't work. I can't get the reasoning of this.

Comment: Listeners want functions that they can call. In 1) you're assigning a function to the listener that calls `holdDice` when the event is fired. In 2) You're calling `holdDice` and assigning the _result_ of calling that function to the listener.

Comment: In more general javascript terms (I know, not even React!) it's the difference between immediately executing it or wrapping it for execution later. In this case, if you do `{holdDice(die.id)}` it get executed immediately and its value will inserted there instead of a method call. If you pass in `() => holdDice(die.id)`, it will execute it on render as it's a function.